# Xcode Instruments (Leaks and Zombies) exits right after startup

Tags: xcode, instruments

I'm trying to profile my iOS app and Leaks and Zombies exits about 2 seconds after the program starts up. I see some allocations being made, but the program just exits with no run issues for some reason. Instruments Allocations runs the program no problem and does not exit. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a log somewhere I can look? I'm using XCode version 9.4(9F1027a).
Thank you for your help.